# Libraries for XML Schema Flattening

Tags: c#, c++, xml, xsd, flat

There is a set of N XSD files which may refer to each other (with `include/import/redefine tags`). The task is to convert this set of N XSD-files into minimum possible number of M XSD-files. Conversion implies inserting included files in-place where possible, resolving references etc.

This feature successfully works in some UI XML editors.

Is there any free or commercial library (native or .NET) that lets me perform XML Schema flattening? Or maybe there are some references to flattening algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a library. Using the standard .NET schema classes this is the code that convert an XSD with a bunch of includes into a single one:

```
static private void ResolveExternal(
  XmlSchema rootSchema, 
  XmlSchema curSchema,
  List<string> processed
)
{
  // Loop on all the includes
  foreach (XmlSchemaExternal external in curSchema.Includes) {
    // Avoid processing twice the same include file
    if (!processed.Contains(external.SchemaLocation)) {
      processed.Add(external.SchemaLocation);
      XmlSchema cur = external.Schema;
      // Recursive calls to handle includes inside the include
      ResolveExternal(rootSchema, cur, processed);
      // Move the items from the included schema to the root one
      foreach (XmlSchemaObject item in cur.Items) {
        rootSchema.Items.Add(item);
      }
    }
  }
  curSchema.Includes.Clear();
} // ResolveExternal

static public void ResolveExternal(XmlSchema schema)
{
  List<string> processed = new List<string>();
  ResolveExternal(schema, schema, processed);
} // ResolveExternal
```

You should be able to handle imports and redefine in a similar way.